# Matching an array of people for gift giving, how to handle this edge case

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I'm matching an array of people to each other. They can't be matched with themselves and each person can only be matched with one other. I have worked this out but run into an edge case. If the person being matched is themselves the only person who has not yet been matched against, we are stuck.

Example:

```
$names = array('Dad','Mom','Harrald','Yu','Sandra','Dave', 'Andy & Kim');
$drawn = array();
$tn = count($names)-1;
$i = mt_rand(0, $tn);

foreach ($names as $name) {        
    while($name == $names[$i] || in_array($names[$i], $drawn)) {
            $i = mt_rand(0, $tn);
    }
    echo $name. ' has ' . $names[$i].'<br />';
    array_push($drawn, $names[$i]);
}
```

This could produce:
Dad has Sandra
Mom has Yu
Harrald has Dave
... etc, etc.

The problem is when it gets to the last element in the array, 'Andy & Kim', if 'Andy & Kim' are the only element not yet added to the `$drawn` array then we have an edge case because you can't match 'Andy & Kim' to themselves. In my example this can result in getting trapped in that while loop and eventually timing out... see what I mean? How would you handle this (this is solely for my own amusement as I went to knock out a quick gift giving match-up script for my Mom to use and realized this was a potential problem).

Oh, better ways to implement such a pattern would be most interesting to see. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Surely, rather than using iteration, it's easier just to shuffle the array; and then match 1st to 2nd, 2nd to 3rd, etc, with the last being matched to the 1st again to complete the circle

Answer (score 1):

You need to backtrack at that point. There are many algorithms which require backtracking, because (as you've found) it turns out that a choice you made at an earlier stage was actually impossible. 
You'll need to store the previous choice points in some way, so that when you hit impossibility (or succeed, if your task is to elicit all solutions) you can go back to the last not-fully-explored choice, and make a different choice.

Answer (score 0):

Without matching someone that already has a match, you can't. That's how odd numbers work. :/

So either match with someone who already has a match, or ask your teacher not to give you bad inputs. ;)

Comment: Obviously. My point is, how would you deal with it? I figured someone would think this was a homework assignment... lol... I wish I were young enough to still be student.

Comment: That's really an issue for how YOU'D like to address the issue. But if what you mean is, how should you overload one of the people already picked with another person... Pick one at random? You could then take those 3 and make a ring out of them. Or, do the whole thing as a big ring. My point. It isn't a programming problem, it is a requirements problem.